# How do i calculate minimum and maximum for groups in a sequence in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I am having the following data in my database table in SQL Server:

```
Id  Date        Val_A   Val_B   Val_C   Avg     Vector  MINMAXPOINTS
329 2016-01-15  78.09   68.40   70.29   76.50   BELOW   68.40
328 2016-01-14  79.79   75.40   76.65   76.67   BELOW   75.40
327 2016-01-13  81.15   74.59   79.00   76.44   ABOVE   81.15
326 2016-01-12  81.95   77.04   78.95   76.04   ABOVE   81.95
325 2016-01-11  82.40   73.65   81.34   75.47   ABOVE   82.40
324 2016-01-08  78.75   73.40   77.20   74.47   ABOVE   78.75
323 2016-01-07  76.40   72.29   72.95   73.74   BELOW   72.29
322 2016-01-06  81.25   77.70   78.34   73.12   ABOVE   81.25
321 2016-01-05  81.75   76.34   80.54   72.08   ABOVE   81.75
320 2016-01-04  80.95   75.15   76.29   70.86   ABOVE   80.95
```

The column `MIMMAXPOINTS` should actually contain lowest of `Val_B` until `Vector` is `'BELOW'` and highest of `Val_A` until `Vector` is `'ABOVE'`. So, we would have the following values in `MINMAXPOINTS`:

```
MINMAXPOINTS
68.40
68.40
82.40
82.40
82.40
82.40
72.29
81.75
81.75
81.75
```

Is it possible without cursor?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first apply classic `gaps-and-islands` to determine groups (gaps/islands/above/below) and then calculate `MIN` and `MAX` for each group.

I assume that `ID` column defines the order of rows.

Tested on SQL Server 2008. Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d6954dd72e53b9015d2a6e6546058f8/15/0).

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
([Id] int, [dt] date, [Val_A] float, [Val_B] float, [Val_C] float, [Avg] float, 
[Vector] varchar(5));

INSERT INTO @T ([Id], [dt], [Val_A], [Val_B], [Val_C], [Avg], [Vector]) VALUES
(329, '2016-01-15', 78.09, 68.40, 70.29, 76.50, 'BELOW'),
(328, '2016-01-14', 79.79, 75.40, 76.65, 76.67, 'BELOW'),
(327, '2016-01-13', 81.15, 74.59, 79.00, 76.44, 'ABOVE'),
(326, '2016-01-12', 81.95, 77.04, 78.95, 76.04, 'ABOVE'),
(325, '2016-01-11', 82.40, 73.65, 81.34, 75.47, 'ABOVE'),
(324, '2016-01-08', 78.75, 73.40, 77.20, 74.47, 'ABOVE'),
(323, '2016-01-07', 76.40, 72.29, 72.95, 73.74, 'BELOW'),
(322, '2016-01-06', 81.25, 77.70, 78.34, 73.12, 'ABOVE'),
(321, '2016-01-05', 81.75, 76.34, 80.54, 72.08, 'ABOVE'),
(320, '2016-01-04', 80.95, 75.15, 76.29, 70.86, 'ABOVE');
```

**Query**

To understand better how it works examine results of each CTE.

`CTE_RowNumbers` calculates two sequences of row numbers.

`CTE_Groups` assigns a number for each group (above/below).

`CTE_MinMax` calculates `MIN/MAX` for each group.

Final `SELECT` picks `MIN` or `MAX` to return.

```
WITH
CTE_RowNumbers
AS
(
    SELECT [Id], [dt], [Val_A], [Val_B], [Val_C], [Avg], [Vector]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vector ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn2
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT [Id], [dt], [Val_A], [Val_B], [Val_C], [Avg], [Vector]
        ,rn1-rn2 AS Groups
    FROM CTE_RowNumbers
)
,CTE_MinMax
AS
(
    SELECT [Id], [dt], [Val_A], [Val_B], [Val_C], [Avg], [Vector]
        ,MAX(Val_A) OVER(PARTITION BY Groups) AS MaxA
        ,MIN(Val_B) OVER(PARTITION BY Groups) AS MinB
    FROM CTE_Groups
)
SELECT [Id], [dt], [Val_A], [Val_B], [Val_C], [Avg], [Vector]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [Vector] = 'BELOW' THEN MinB
        WHEN [Vector] = 'ABOVE' THEN MaxA
    END AS MINMAXPOINTS
FROM CTE_MinMax
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

**Result**

```
+-----+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+
| Id  |     dt     | Val_A | Val_B | Val_C |  Avg  | Vector | MINMAXPOINTS |
+-----+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+
| 329 | 2016-01-15 | 78.09 | 68.4  | 70.29 | 76.5  | BELOW  | 68.4         |
| 328 | 2016-01-14 | 79.79 | 75.4  | 76.65 | 76.67 | BELOW  | 68.4         |
| 327 | 2016-01-13 | 81.15 | 74.59 | 79    | 76.44 | ABOVE  | 82.4         |
| 326 | 2016-01-12 | 81.95 | 77.04 | 78.95 | 76.04 | ABOVE  | 82.4         |
| 325 | 2016-01-11 | 82.4  | 73.65 | 81.34 | 75.47 | ABOVE  | 82.4         |
| 324 | 2016-01-08 | 78.75 | 73.4  | 77.2  | 74.47 | ABOVE  | 82.4         |
| 323 | 2016-01-07 | 76.4  | 72.29 | 72.95 | 73.74 | BELOW  | 72.29        |
| 322 | 2016-01-06 | 81.25 | 77.7  | 78.34 | 73.12 | ABOVE  | 81.75        |
| 321 | 2016-01-05 | 81.75 | 76.34 | 80.54 | 72.08 | ABOVE  | 81.75        |
| 320 | 2016-01-04 | 80.95 | 75.15 | 76.29 | 70.86 | ABOVE  | 81.75        |
+-----+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, that was an awesome solution!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query using case statment which will let you select a conditional value based on vector value for each row.

The query is

```
SELECT ID, DATE, VAL_A, VAL_B, VAL_C, AVG, VECTOR, 
CASE
    WHEN VECTOR = 'BELOW' THEN (SELECT MIN(VAL_B) FROM TABLE A)
    WHEN VECTOR = 'ABOVE' THEN (SELECT MAX(VAL_A) FROM TABLE A)
END AS MINMAXVALUE
FROM TABLE B
GO
```

Check if this help you.

Comment: replace Table name with actual table name

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Your code yielded the maximum and minimum of all the values in the table. But i'm looking for a solution for groups of data in a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the query to check for group of data greater than current records as
You can use below query using case statment which will let you select a conditional value based on vector value for each row.

The query is

```
SELECT ID, DATE, VAL_A, VAL_B, VAL_C, AVG, VECTOR,
  CASE
    WHEN VECTOR = 'BELOW' THEN (SELECT MIN(VAL_B) FROM TABLE A WHERE ROWID >= B.ROWID)
    WHEN VECTOR = 'ABOVE' THEN (SELECT MAX(VAL_A) FROM TABLE A WHERE ROWID >= B.ROWID)
   END AS MINMAXVALUE

FROM TABLE B 
GO
```

Check this should yield the result you are expecting from the data.

Comment: You should edit your existing question rather than posting a new one

Comment: Your variant doesn't return expected results.